# Is there a way to make PHP get the values of second Row downwards in a table?

Tags: php, sql

I defined specific values in a table with several rows, stored in mysql database on a table named signals for each user using their emails. The user in turn is fills a form which PHP will check against the defined values in the signal table, if all values matches any of the user row, action is executed, else, another action is executed. When i fill the exact values on the first row into the form, it returns that values matches row, but when i submit the values on the second or third row or any other, it returns that Values do not match row.

Here is my PHP Code, please direct me on what i am doing wrong

```
$tempo = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM signals WHERE email = '$email'");
$tempo->execute(); 
$rowq = $tempo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // assuming a button named buy is clicked 

if(isset($_POST['buy'])) {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
        
        
    $category = trim($_POST['category']);
    $category = strip_tags($category);
    $category = htmlspecialchars($category);
    
    
    $trading_pair = trim($_POST['trading_pair']);
    $trading_pair = strip_tags($trading_pair);
    $trading_pair = htmlspecialchars($trading_pair);
    
    
    $strike_rate = trim($_POST['strike_rate']);
    $strike_rate = strip_tags($strike_rate);
    $strike_rate = htmlspecialchars($strike_rate);
    
    
    $amount = trim($_POST['amount']);
    $amount = strip_tags($amount);
    $amount = htmlspecialchars($amount);
    
    $interval = trim($_POST['interval']);
    $interval = strip_tags($interval);
    $interval = htmlspecialchars($interval);
    
    $time = trim($_POST['time']);
    $time = strip_tags($time);
    $time = htmlspecialchars($time);


    if($_POST['email'] == $rowq['email']  AND 
        $_POST['category'] == $rowq['category'] AND 
        $_POST['trading_pair'] == $rowq['trading_pair'] AND 
        $_POST['strike_rate'] == $rowq['strike_rate'] AND 
        $_POST['amount'] == $rowq['amount'] AND
        $_POST['interval'] == $rowq['interval']) 
    {
        echo '<script>alert("Input Values Matches row");</script> ';   // row exists. do whatever you would like to do.
    } else {
        echo '<script>alert("Input Values do not match row");</script> ';    // row does not exists. do whatever you would like to do.
    }
```

It returns Input Values Matches row when i fill in the details on the first row with the first ID but when i fill in the details of the second row below, it always returns Input Values do not match row... I hope i get help with this. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Below is the sql for the table;

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Jan 13, 2021 at 06:18 AM
-- Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-log-cll-lve
-- PHP Version: 7.3.6

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `admizafr_lanky`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `signals`
--

CREATE TABLE `signals` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `trading_pair` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `strike_rate` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `interval` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(2000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `signals`
--

INSERT INTO `signals` (`id`, `email`, `category`, `trading_pair`, `strike_rate`, `amount`, `interval`, `time`) VALUES
(1, 'Aliuabdulrauf@gmail.com', 'cryptocurrency', 'BCH/EUR', '4;67', '1000', '1', 'success'),
(2, 'Aliuabdulrauf@gmail.com', 'cryptocurrency', 'BCH/USD', '50;2', '1500', '1', 'success'),
(5, 'Aliuabdulrauf@gmail.com', 'cryptocurrency', 'BCH/GBPj', '22;6', '10000', '5', 'success');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `signals`
--
ALTER TABLE `signals`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `signals`
--
ALTER TABLE `signals`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: You `trim()` and `strip_tags()` and `htmlspecialchars()` each `$_POST` value and then you  run an IF using the raw `$_POST` values. That makes little sense. Did you do all that to the data that you stored on the table before storing it?

Comment: Can you show us the schema for `signals` and some relevant example data from that table please

Comment: If you have multiple rows for this user then you either need a loop over the rows and check each in turn OR you have to have a column that identifies this specific situation and add that to the WHERE clause to get just one row returned from the query

Comment: Just as @RiggsFolly said, it is likely that you made a small mistake, either when typing, either in the database. There are a lot of fields, and even a simple space character will negate the condition.

Comment: I have added the sql table @RiggsFolly

Comment: Then cant you use `category` on the query WHERE clause to get the matching `signal` to what the user is actually entering?

Comment: You use `time varchar(2000)` but enter `success` into it ?? `interval varchar(2000)` but enter `'1'` into it???  `amount varchar(2000)` and you enter an `integer 1000` into that col ?????????????

Comment: Also, you have the same email on all 3 rows, isn't that a mistake? $rowq should be an array.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, i am new and learning PHP. Can you please point me right by putting it into an answer? Especially how i can also get thesame results as that of the first row when the second row matches with the submitted inputs?

Comment: @BadeaMihaiFlorin Yes i have thesame email, so i can retrieve the datas for users seperately with their email. How do i make it an array? Am new with PHP.

Comment: Add a different email for each row, and try again. It should work. I think the select query is always returning the first row.

Comment: You are using prepared statement so you should use condition in `WHERE email = ?"; execute([$email]);` and sanitize strings to match both side `$email = $this->sanitize('email');` and in foreach `sanitize($_POST['email']) == $rowq['email'];` and date coulmn in db `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`

Comment: @BadeaMihaiFlorin the idea is that the user does not enter their email, they login and the form retrieves their email from their profile. The signal table can hold upto 5 rows for a user with thesame email.

Comment: Trading Pair looks unique within email, so add that to the where clause, from the users input

Comment: Ok, i understand, but what do you have in $rowq variable, for the email Aliuabdulrauf@gmail.com. Test and print it. Is it an array, or just one row? I don't know what those function return.

Comment: I'm getting confused. The code i provided above works fine when the filled form matches the details for the first row. but when it matches for the second or any other, it says the values do not match

Comment: @BadeaMihaiFlorin it only displays one email and when i print for even the trading pairs which has unique values in each row, it prints only the value on the first row

Comment: Then that is the problem. You always get the first value from the database. And you try to compare it by entering data from others.

Comment: @BadeaMihaiFlorin how do i make it get values from any row and works in so far it matches any row? Can you point me right with an answer ? Pleasse!!!

Answer (score -1):

You need to gather all rows inside database with that email and loop-compare them.

```php
function compare() {
    if(!isset($_POST['buy'])) {
        return;
    }

    $tempo = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM signals WHERE email = '$email'");
    $tempo->execute(); 
    $rows = $tempo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $email = $this->sanitize('email');
    $category = $this->sanitize('category');
    /* ... */

    foreach ($rows as $rowq) {
        if(
            $email == $rowq['email'] && 
            $category == $rowq['category'] && 
            $trading_pair == $rowq['trading_pair'] && 
            $strike_rate == $rowq['strike_rate'] && 
            $amount == $rowq['amount'] &&
            $interval == $rowq['interval']
        ) {
            echo '<script>alert("Input Values Matches row");</script> ';   // row exists. do whatever you would like to do.

            return;
        }
    }

    echo '<script>alert("Input Values do not match row");</script> ';    // row does not exists. do whatever you would like to do.
}

function sanitize($input) {
    $output = trim($_POST[$input]);
    $output = strip_tags($output);
    $output = htmlspecialchars($output);

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I did exactly this but when i submit now, it reloads page without any response!

Comment: OP using prepared statement so you should use condition in `WHERE email = ?"; execute([$email]);` and sanitize strings to match both side `$email = $this->sanitize('email');` and in foreach `sanitize($_POST['email']) == $rowq['email'];` and date coulmn in db `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`

Answer (score -1):

I made some changes to the original code, to fix some mistakes and add improvements. You can find explanations in the comments. But like i said, please read more about php principles.

```
// Use prepared statements to sanitize user input in queries, like bellow.
$tempo = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM signals WHERE email = ?");
$tempo->execute([$email]);
$rows = $tempo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Call the function for each input ( see, the code looks tidy already )
$email = sanitize($_POST['email']);          
$category = sanitize($_POST['category']);
$trading_pair = sanitize($_POST['trading_pair']);
$strike_rate = sanitize($_POST['strike_rate']);
$amount = sanitize($_POST['amount']);
$interval = sanitize($_POST['interval']);
$time = sanitize($_POST['time']); // This one is not used, check it.

// assuming a button named buy is clicked
// Loop trough each row in the database
foreach ($rows as $rowq) {
    if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
        // Use the variables you sanitized (not from $_POST), and compare them with the one in the database
        // Beware that there are also && and || operators, check the differences between them,
        // because in some cases they will not work as expected.
        if ($email == $rowq['email'] AND
        $category == $rowq['category'] AND
        $trading_pair == $rowq['trading_pair'] AND
        $strike_rate == $rowq['strike_rate'] AND
        $amount == $rowq['amount'] AND
        $interval == $rowq['interval']) {
            echo '<script>alert("Input Values Matches row");</script> ';   // row exists. do whatever you would like to do.
        } else {
            echo '<script>alert("Input Values do not match row");</script> ';    // row does not exists. do whatever you would like to do.
        }
    }
}

// Create a functions, like this, with parameters, for duplicate code.
// It makes the code easier to read
function sanitize($input) {
  // Also, you can nest functions that return a value,
  // and not assign it to a variable, to make it even shorter
  return htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($input)));
}
```

Comment: @Dharman, yes, i know, and there are other issues, haven't you read what i said? He barely knows the basics of PHP, like functions and loops, there was no point of complicating things. I just wanted him to understand what changes i made to his code. After that, i hope he will learn to improve it.

Comment: Please note that you are not writing an answer just for one person. You are writing it for everyone else who read this. Parameter binding is simpler than string interpolation so you would not be complicating anything. There is absolutely no reason to post wrong answers, please fix it.

Comment: Syntax error `$email = sanitize($_POST['email'])));` also fetchAll doesnt display data it should be  `fetch();` 1 row. After that corrections it will run an infinite load and keep displaying values not match :)

Comment: Typo, sorry. Yes, it will display depending on how many rws he has in db. He can change the code and not run that js every time, or do whatever he wants. Or not run it at all, that is bad practice anyway.